# How to implement fractal flames in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, fractals

See [Wiki](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0YZy.jpg) and  the description  [here](http://flam3.com/flame_draves.pdf) .
[image]

Here is my attempt to realize the pseudocode in p.3:

```
F[0][x_, y_] := {x/2, y/2}
F[1][x_, y_] := {x/2 + 1/2, y/2}
F[2][x_, y_] := {x/2, y/2 + 1/2}
Do[Do[x = Random[];y = Random[]; {x, y} = F[RandomInteger[2]][x, y],
  20]; Print[x, y], 5]
```

> Set::write: Tag CompoundExpression in x=Random[]; is Protected.
> General::stop: Further output of Set::write will be suppressed during this calculation.
>
> 0.07520640.267655B
>
> 0.8007930.190645
>
> 0.7525410.000367346
>
> 0.2011730.0475016
>
> 0.3844770.0957375

Comment: I think you are just missing a `y` in your second initial definition within Do. i.e. `x = Random[]; = Random[];` should be `x = Random[]; y = Random[];`

Comment: @MarcoB: Thank you. Fixed.

Comment: You will also want to use `Sow` and `Reap` rather than Print to collect your results. Try e.g. `Reap[Do[Do[x = Random[]; y = Random[]; {x, y} = F[RandomInteger[2]][x, y], 20]; Sow[{x, y}], 1000]][[2, 1]]; ListPlot[%]` This generates [this plot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zqgho.png) with no errors, but I am not sure whether that's what you want.

Comment: @MarkoB: It's kind of you. Many thanks from me to you. Your plot is not it. The Serpinski carpet should be produced. It would be nice to create a general procedure to produce a fractal flame. Unfortunately, my skills are not sufficient to this end.

Comment: +1 because it looks like the mathematica logo almost in the center

Comment: 1/2 hour of reading, 1/2 hour of hacking and 1/2 of trying different variations: [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9aLD.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your own definitions of `F[i]` from OP, here is a literal implementation of the algorithm you pointed to on page 3 of the linked paper. it does not seem to produce a flame, but rather a Sierpinski triangle, as far as I understand it.

```
Module[{x, y},
  {x, y} = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2];
  Reap[
   Do[Sow[{x, y} = F[RandomInteger[{0, 2}]][x, y]], 10000]
  ][[2, 1, 21 ;;]] (*take only iterations after the first 20*)
];

ListPlot[%]
```

---

Here is a more idiomatic implementation of the same algorithm in *Mathematica*:

```
ListPlot@
 NestList[F[RandomInteger[{0, 2}]] @@ # &, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2], 10000][[21;;]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Here are some examples of other functions that were in the original paper:

```
ClearAll[v]
v[0][{x_, y_}] := {x, y}
v[1][{x_, y_}] := {Sin[x], Cos[x]}
v[2][{x_, y_}] := Normalize[{x, y}]
v[3][{x_, y_}] := With[{rsquare = SquaredEuclideanDistance[x, y]}, {x Sin[rsquare] - y Cos[rsquare], x Cos[rsquare] + y Sin[rsquare]}]
v[4][{x_, y_}] := {x^2 - y^2, 2 x y}/EuclideanDistance[x, y]

NestList[v[RandomInteger[{0, 4}]][#] &, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2], 150000][[20 ;;]];

ListPlot[%, PlotRange -> {-10, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is now up to you to define "interesting" functions and try them out, them find an appropriate coloring scheme, etc.

Comment: +1. How about the general case?

Comment: @user64494 What do you mean by "general" here?

Comment: I have in mind arbitrary functions $F[i]$ and more complicated flames.

Comment: @user64494 I added some more functions from the paper, page 5. However, there is much more to making those beautiful images than just generating some points: you will have to choose an appropriate coloring scheme, perhaps some filtering of results, etc.

Comment: I will wait for other answers before accepting yours. It's a pity that Apophysis beats Mathematica here.

Comment: @user64494 I'd say that it is completely unsurprising that a single-purpose software package will do its only purpose better than a general purpose tool like *Mathematica*. In fact, if it didn't, there would be no point in its existence at all! Note also that all the formatting decisions have already been pre-implemented there. However, I'm sure that *Mathematica* beats Apophysis handily at, say, numerical and symbolic integration, formula manipulation, and cluster analysis, to name but a few random things... ;-)

Comment: @user64494 Check this implementation out. http://ankov.blogspot.com/2010/12/rendering-fractal-flames-with.html